# WordPress custom query variable in an if statement behaving oddly

Tags: php, wordpress

I have some php bringing in data from a non WordPress database on a WordPress custom template page. I want to redirect using the php header function if the query var doesn't exist like:

```
if (qv_isset('id')) {
  $id = urldecode($wp_query->query_vars['id']);
  $results = $fhr_db->query("SELECT Game.* WHERE Game.GameID=$id");
  if ($results->num_rows) {
    $game = $results->fetch_object();
    $results->free();
  } else {
    header("location: " . $site_url . "/games-admin/?msg=Error: No game with that ID.");
  }
} else {
  header("location: " . $site_url . "/games-admin/?msg=Error: No ID given.");
}
```

The issue is when there is a query variable 'id', then the last header() is called. If I change the contents of the final else to:

```
else {
  echo "fire";
}
```

the if contents will run as it should and 'fire' will not be echoed. This only happens when redirecting with header() from the same page like this:

```
header("location: " . $site_url . "/game-edit/?id=$id&msg=Game added.");
```

I think im using the header function incorrectly. Can someone explain why this is happening, particularly how the code within an if else statement can change the evaluation of the condition?

This is the qv_isset function:

```
function qv_isset($var_name) {
  $array = $GLOBALS['wp_query']->query_vars;
  return array_key_exists($var_name, $array);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use wordpress function `wp_redirect` function for redirect on new page or same page reload and also must use `exit(0)` function after `wp_redirect` function.